# Can't access object method

Tags: javascript

I've created a quasi namespace/class called NewsCalendar. My intent is to avoid polluting the global namespace as well as hide functions that should be private. But when I try to call what should be a public method I get "Object does not support this property or method."

```
function NewsCalendar()
{
    var privatevar; //private vars

    this.onLoad = function () //public method
    {
        //Do Stuff
    };

    function getWeekStart(date) //private function
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

The comments are there to indicate how I'm intending each item to behave.

I tried calling the onLoad function like this:

```
NewsCalendar.onLoad();
```

But that causes the "object does not support this property or method" error. I want to be able to use NewsCalendar like a namespace and be able to call any variables/methods attached to its this object by using NewsCalendar.propertyname or NewsCalendar.methodname().

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer? If so, choose one and accept it. Otherwise, explain what's happening

Comment: Yours works. I just don't like using return that way. Not your fault, I just find javascript syntax really ugly sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following setup:

```
var NewsCalendar = (function () {
    var privatevar;

    var onLoadHandler = function () {
        //Do Stuff
    };

    function getWeekStart(date) {
        //Do Stuff
    }

    return {
        onLoad: onLoadHandler
    };
})();
```

And then use:

```
NewsCalendar.onLoad();
```

Anything in the returned `{}` is public. Anything inside of the surrounding function is accessible only by anything inside of it.

The reason I suggest this setup is because you don't seem to want to instantitate several objects, but instead use it as a library of properties/methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create instance:

```
var calendar = new NewsCalendar();
calendar.onLoad();
```